# Should I use retrofit with a singleton?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit and want to know what's the best practice.

Here is some abstracted code that I found online:

```
public class RestClient

{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "your base url";
    private ApiService apiService;

    public RestClient()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory()) // This is the important line ;)
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public ApiService getApiService()
    {
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

and lets say I want to make a api request/call with this function

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.getApiService().getPosts();
```

My question is should I make a new restClient object or this should be a singleton, or the ApiService should be a singleton.

What's the best practice? Please keep in mind that I don't want to use dependency injection, I just want to understand how best to use retrofit.

How would some of you make this call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you have is fine. You can keep the restClient as a singleton, and then just call `restClient.getApiService().getPosts();` whenever you want to get the posts again (don't create a new restClient each time).

Comment: if is a singleton, can it handle two or more api requests in parallel?

Comment: Yes, it can handle many parallel requests - I'm not sure what the limit is, but when you exceed that, it will queue the request (assuming that you are using it asynchronously, which you should).

I've successfully thrown a dozen or more async requests at it in quick succession, without worrying about how many outstanding requests there are.

Comment: Hi. I wanna know, what if I will not use retrofit singleton class and instead I will create new retrofit instance every time. What problem it will cause? Maybe memory leaks or something else?

Answer (score 10):

You should make `RestClient` as singleton in any way that you like (enum, standard `getInstance()` or even `double check`).

Keeping them as singleton will increase performance, because you will not create each time costful objects like `Gson`, `RestAdapter` and `ApiService`.

**Edit:**
Max requests which could be handled at the same time by Retrofit is dependent on HttpClient configuration.

When using with `OkHttp` default value is 64 (it is defined in [`Dispatcher`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7135628c645892faf1a48a8cff464e0ed4ad88cb/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java#L39)).

However it can be manipulated via [`setMaxRequests()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7135628c645892faf1a48a8cff464e0ed4ad88cb/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java#L77), keep in mind to not spawn too many threads (it can lead to OutOfMemory).

Comment: Hi. I wanna know, what if I will not use retrofit singleton class and instead I will create new retrofit instance every time. What problem it will cause? Maybe memory leaks or something else?